# How should I interpret this notation?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions, normal-distribution

I am reading some lecture notes and I'm not sure how to interpret this:
$$ b_j(x)=p(x\mid s_j)=N(x;\mu,\sigma^2)$$
It is clear from the context that $N$ refers to normal distribution, but what exactly is $N(x;\mu,\sigma^2)$? Does it denote normal CDF?

Comment: I suspect it means the density function.

Answer (score 1):

i would interpret it as the normal density function. does it make sense for you?

Comment: It doesn't. From the context, it has to be a probability (i.e. between 0 and 1)

Comment: @user798275 Yes, that is what user248841 said.  The context suggests $p(x\mid s_j) = N(x; \mu, \sigma^2)$ is the *probability density function* of a *normal distribution* with parameters for mean of $\mu$ and variance of $\sigma^2$.
$$N(x; \mu, \sigma^2) = \dfrac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi\sigma^2}}\;\exp\left(-\dfrac{(x-\mu)^2 }{ 2\sigma^2}\right)$$

Answer (score 1):

Remember that the normal distribution is parametrized by its mean and variance which are usually denoted by $\mu$ and $\sigma^2$, respectively. The notation $f(x;\theta) $ generally means $ f $ is a function of $ x $ parametrized by $\theta $. $ N $ is referring to the normal density function.